# OpenCV Error MagicMirror AttributeError: 'cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, magic-mirror

**Config:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8 
"""MMMM-Facial-Recognition-OCV3 - MagicMirror Module The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2018 Mathieu Goulène (MIT License) Based on work by Paul-Vincent Roll (Copyright 2016) (MIT License) """

# to install builtins run `pip install future` from builtins import input

import cv2 import numpy as np import os

from lib.tools.config import ToolsConfig from lib.common.face import FaceDetection

class ToolsTrain:
    def __init__(self):

        self.face = ToolsConfig.getFaceDetection()

    def prepareImage(self, filename):
        """Read an image as grayscale and resize it to the appropriate size for
        training the face recognition model.
        """
        return self.face.resize(cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),ToolsConfig.FACE_WIDTH, ToolsConfig.FACE_HEIGHT)


    def train(self):
        print("Reading training images...")
        print('-' * 20)
        faces = []
        labels = []
        imageDirsWithLabel = [[0, "negative"]]
        imageDirs = os.listdir(ToolsConfig.TRAINING_DIR)
        imageDirs = [x for x in imageDirs if not x.startswith('.') and not x.startswith('negative')]
        pos_count = 0

        for i in range(len(imageDirs)):
            print("Assign label " + str(i + 1) + " to " + imageDirs[i])
            imageDirsWithLabel.append([i + 1, imageDirs[i]])
        print('-' * 20)
        print('')

        # Für jedes Label/Namen Paar:
        # for every label/name pair:
        for j in range(0, len(imageDirsWithLabel)):
            # Label zu den Labels hinzufügen / Bilder zu den Gesichtern
            for filename in ToolsConfig.walkFiles(ToolsConfig.TRAINING_DIR + str(imageDirsWithLabel[j][1]), '*.pgm'):
                faces.append(self.prepareImage(filename))
                labels.append(imageDirsWithLabel[j][0])
                if imageDirsWithLabel[j][0] != 0:
                    pos_count += 1

        # Print statistic on how many pictures per person we have collected
        print('Read '  + str(pos_count) + ' positive images and ' + str(labels.count(0)) + ' negative images.')
        print('')
        for j in range(1, max(labels) + 1):
            print(str(labels.count(j)) + " images from subject " + imageDirs[j - 1])

        # Train model
        print('-' * 20)
        print('')
```

**CMD:**
`sudo python tools.train.py`

**Error/Output**

```
Remember to set the name list environment variable FACE_USERS Reading
training images...
-------------------- Assign label 1 to Jorick
--------------------

Read 7 positive images and 0 negative images.

7 images from subject Jorick
--------------------

Training model with threshold 80 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools.train.py", line 14, in <module>
    ToolsTrain().train()   File "/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-Facial-Recognition-OCV3/lib/tools/train.py",
line 74, in train
    model.write(ToolsConfig.TRAINING_FILE) AttributeError: 'cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**Git package:**
https://github.com/normyx/MMM-Facial-Recognition-OCV3

**Python version:**
Python 2.7.16

Comment: It seems that you are using an old version of OpenCV, in order to run MMM-Facial-Recognition-OCV3 you will need OpenCV 3.3, anything older than that will fail as the interface of cv::face::FaceRecognizer was changed between 3.2 and 3.3.
Read the MMM-Facial-Recognition-OCV3 repository readme file - it explains how to install the package dependencies

Comment: @Black0ut i cant find it.